# Does it exist a family $A$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, with special propertie listed below?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Does it exist a family $A$ of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, such that $A$ has cardinality of continuum and for any two elements of $A$ one of them is subsets of another? Note - elements of $A$ are subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: When you say "any two elements of A are subsets of each other" do you mean that given $a,b \in A,$ either $a \subset b$ or $b \subset a$?

Comment: @Ross Millikan Yes, I will edit it now.

Comment: The set of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ is indeed countable, so if $A$ only contained finite sets, then it couldn't be as large as the continuum. However, there's no reason the elements of $A$ must have the same cardinality nor that they may not be infinite, so there is still doubt as to whether there may be continuum many of them.

Comment: @Mello, yes, you are right, that is because I made initial mistake in problem statement. I realised it after edits. So I will correct the statement now. Hopefully Guest provide perfect answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the sets $A_r = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x < r\}$ for each real $r$.

Comment: Elements of $A_r$ must be natural numbers.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so there is a function $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{N}$, so consider $f(A_r)$

Comment: $A_i$ and $A_j$ are not subsets of each other when $i$ and $j$ are different.

Comment: @Hedgehog: If you enumerate $\Bbb Q$ as $q_n$, and take $A_r=\{n\mid q_n<r\}$ then for $r<r'$ we have that $A_r\subseteq A_r'$.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Why $A_r$ is uncountable?

Comment: $A_r$ is a set of rationals. The family $\{A_r : r \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is what you want.

Comment: Ok, it is perfect, i missed $r$ is real. thanks a lot! I will accept it now.